# Proof that integral is negative by elasticities

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

i have two functions:

1) $y =f(x)$ with $ f(x)> 0$ and $ f^{\prime}(x) \leq 0$

2) $y =g(x)$ with $ g(x)> 0$ and $ g^{\prime}(x) < 0$

Furthermore i know that the elasticities $\epsilon_{f(x),x} = \frac{df\left(x\right)}{dx}\frac{x}{f\left(x\right)} \leq 0$ and $\epsilon_{g(x),x} < 0$  $\epsilon_{g(x),x} <\epsilon_{f(x),x}$ and for every x

Furthermore i have the integral with a,b > 0 and i as a constant
$NPV=\int_{a}^{b}{\left(1+i\right)^{-t}\ (g\left(x\right)-f\left(x\right))\ dx} = 0$

Now suppose i have the integral 
$NPV=\int_{a}^{b + \Delta{x} }{\left(1+i\right)^{-t}\ (g\left(x\right)-f\left(x\right))\ dx} $

How can i prove this integral is negative?

$\int_{a}^{b + \Delta{x} }{\left(1+i\right)^{-t}\ (g\left(x\right)-f\left(x\right))\ dx} $

= $\int_{a}^{b}{\left(1+i\right)^{-t}\ (g\left(x\right)-f\left(x\right))\ dx} + \int_{b}^{b + \Delta t}{\left(1+i\right)^{-t}\ (g\left(x\right)-f\left(x\right))\ dx}$

$ = 0 + \int_{b}^{b + \Delta t}{\left(1+i\right)^{-t}\ (g\left(x\right)-f\left(x\right))\ dx} $

So i have to prove that $\int_{b}^{b + \Delta t}{\left(1+i\right)^{-t}\ (g\left(x\right)-f\left(x\right))\ dx} $ is negative.

I tried different approaches but im quite stuck. Can somebody help me out?

Thank you in advance.